# How can I prevent submit event and with onclick event call ActionResult Method Create to submit my form data using Jquery ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

How can I call action result method using JQuery with onclick event if my button type is submit I tried like this 
`$("#btnSave).click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
@Url.Action("Create","ControllerName");
});`

Comment: What does **call action result method**  means ? You want to submit your form data ?

Comment: Yes to submit data with Jquery calling ActionResult Create Method ?

Comment: See the answer i posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to submit your form data using ajax, you may use the jQuery `serialize()` method to serialize your form and send that.

```
$(function(){

  $("#btnSave").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var _f=$(this).closest("form");
      $.post(_f.attr("action"),_f.seriazlize(),function(response){
         //do something with response
      });
  });

});
```

Assuming your button is inside the form which you want to submit and it has the action attribute value set to Create action method.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Create","YourControllerName"))
{
  <!-- Your other form elements goes here -->
  <input type="button" id="btnSave" />
}
```

Comment: Thx @Shyju I will try yes my button is inside the form and my form action is set on Create

Comment: Sorry @Shyju do you know how can I redirect from this code to another page after inserting ?

Comment: Replace the `//do something with response` inside the $.post success callback with  with `window.location.href='/Home/Index'`;